# WPF - How to put a XAML Icon inside an ImageSource?

Tags: wpf, icons, geometry, imagesource, xceed

I am using Xceed's MessageBox and, as you may know, in order to customize its display image you have to use its `ImageSource` property which is of type `ImageSource`.

Now, I have some cool icons in XAML (taken from [here](http://www.xamalot.com), [here](http://www.thexamlproject.com/) and some that I've made by myself). So I want to use them in an `ImageSource` in order to have them on the MessageBox.

I have searched the web, but the closest I came was with the `DrawingImage` class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But this uses geometries, not normal XAML elements (like `Canvas`, `Path`, `Rectangle`, etc) that my icons use.

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458046/how-to-use-path-in-a-drawingimage), but it doesn't seem to help much.

So, is there a way to put my icons (as they currently are) inside an `ImageSource`?

And if not, is there a way to convert my icons into geometries (using simple C# code or tools like Blend)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do it in pure XAML (unless you want to manually convert your XAML image to a DrawingImage). However, you could render the image to a bitmap using the [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms653503%28v=VS.110,d=hv.2%29.aspx) class, then use that bitmap as the image source.